# override prestashop 1.6 controller and view by module

Tags: php, templates, module, prestashop-1.6

I'm new in developing prestashop, i create first module using tutorial on page, and create my config file.
Now i want to override Admin Orders controller and view.
I'm need to add little form to view that will get some data from my config module and than process it.
As far I understand to achieve that /modules/my_module/override/controllers/admin/AdminOrdersController.php

And inside i create my class. basic markup:

```
class AdminOrdersController extends AdminOrdersControllerCore
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

Now i want to know how inside of my module file i can override template.
Template is inside of: admin999fxzxg5\themes\default\template\controllers\orders\helpers\view.
I try put in folder modules\mymodule\override\controllers\admin\templates\orders\helpers\view but no result.

So my first question is were i can put template file to add form.
And than how can i write function inside of controller to retrieve and pass data in this form.

I was able to override form but only inside override\controllers\admin\templates\orders\helpers\view\
And i'm sure this is wrong way :)
Also i copy and paste whole "AdminOrdersController.php" and just assign one variable ($this->tpl_view_vars....) to check if t works and it did.
Now I want to know is that correct way of doing overrides in prestashop ? Also how can i create link and assign new function inside of my override controller?

I try to follow some doc i Found and end up with this code still its not working any clue what I'm doing wrong way ?
Fow now i just want that var showing up than As sad before run function or update form when link is clicked..
Code for controller that i want to override..

```
    <?php

class AdminOrdersController extends AdminOrdersControllerCore
{
        public function renderView()
    {
        $order = new Order(Tools::getValue('id_order'));
        if (!Validate::isLoadedObject($order))
            $this->errors[] = Tools::displayError('The order cannot be found within your database.');

        $customer = new Customer($order->id_customer);
        $carrier = new Carrier($order->id_carrier);
        $products = $this->getProducts($order);
        $currency = new Currency((int)$order->id_currency);
        // Carrier module call
        $carrier_module_call = null;
        if ($carrier->is_module)
        {
            $module = Module::getInstanceByName($carrier->external_module_name);
            if (method_exists($module, 'displayInfoByCart'))
                $carrier_module_call = call_user_func(array($module, 'displayInfoByCart'), $order->id_cart);
        }

        // Retrieve addresses information
        $addressInvoice = new Address($order->id_address_invoice, $this->context->language->id);
        if (Validate::isLoadedObject($addressInvoice) && $addressInvoice->id_state)
            $invoiceState = new State((int)$addressInvoice->id_state);

        if ($order->id_address_invoice == $order->id_address_delivery)
        {
            $addressDelivery = $addressInvoice;
            if (isset($invoiceState))
                $deliveryState = $invoiceState;
        }
        else
        {
            $addressDelivery = new Address($order->id_address_delivery, $this->context->language->id);
            if (Validate::isLoadedObject($addressDelivery) && $addressDelivery->id_state)
                $deliveryState = new State((int)($addressDelivery->id_state));
        }

        $this->toolbar_title = sprintf($this->l('Order #%1$d (%2$s) - %3$s %4$s'), $order->id, $order->reference, $customer->firstname, $customer->lastname);
        if (Shop::isFeatureActive())
        {
            $shop = new Shop((int)$order->id_shop);
            $this->toolbar_title .= ' - '.sprintf($this->l('Shop: %s'), $shop->name);
        }

        // gets warehouses to ship products, if and only if advanced stock management is activated
        $warehouse_list = null;

        $order_details = $order->getOrderDetailList();
        foreach ($order_details as $order_detail)
        {
            $product = new Product($order_detail['product_id']);

            if (Configuration::get('PS_ADVANCED_STOCK_MANAGEMENT')
                && $product->advanced_stock_management)
            {
                $warehouses = Warehouse::getWarehousesByProductId($order_detail['product_id'], $order_detail['product_attribute_id']);
                foreach ($warehouses as $warehouse)
                {
                    if (!isset($warehouse_list[$warehouse['id_warehouse']]))
                        $warehouse_list[$warehouse['id_warehouse']] = $warehouse;
                }
            }
        }

        $payment_methods = array();
        foreach (PaymentModule::getInstalledPaymentModules() as $payment)
        {
            $module = Module::getInstanceByName($payment['name']);
            if (Validate::isLoadedObject($module) && $module->active)
                $payment_methods[] = $module->displayName;
        }

        // display warning if there are products out of stock
        $display_out_of_stock_warning = false;
        $current_order_state = $order->getCurrentOrderState();
        if (Configuration::get('PS_STOCK_MANAGEMENT') && (!Validate::isLoadedObject($current_order_state) || ($current_order_state->delivery != 1 && $current_order_state->shipped != 1)))
            $display_out_of_stock_warning = true;

        // products current stock (from stock_available)
        foreach ($products as &$product)
        {
            // Get total customized quantity for current product
            $customized_product_quantity = 0;

            if (is_array($product['customizedDatas']))
                foreach ($product['customizedDatas'] as $customizationPerAddress)
                    foreach ($customizationPerAddress as $customizationId => $customization)
                        $customized_product_quantity += (int)$customization['quantity'];

            $product['customized_product_quantity'] = $customized_product_quantity;
            $product['current_stock'] = StockAvailable::getQuantityAvailableByProduct($product['product_id'], $product['product_attribute_id'], $product['id_shop']);
            $resume = OrderSlip::getProductSlipResume($product['id_order_detail']);
            $product['quantity_refundable'] = $product['product_quantity'] - $resume['product_quantity'];
            $product['amount_refundable'] = $product['total_price_tax_excl'] - $resume['amount_tax_excl'];
            $product['amount_refund'] = Tools::displayPrice($resume['amount_tax_incl'], $currency);
            $product['refund_history'] = OrderSlip::getProductSlipDetail($product['id_order_detail']);
            $product['return_history'] = OrderReturn::getProductReturnDetail($product['id_order_detail']);

            // if the current stock requires a warning
            if ($product['current_stock'] == 0 && $display_out_of_stock_warning)
                $this->displayWarning($this->l('This product is out of stock: ').' '.$product['product_name']);
            if ($product['id_warehouse'] != 0)
            {
                $warehouse = new Warehouse((int)$product['id_warehouse']);
                $product['warehouse_name'] = $warehouse->name;
            }
            else
                $product['warehouse_name'] = '--';
        }

        $gender = new Gender((int)$customer->id_gender, $this->context->language->id);

        $history = $order->getHistory($this->context->language->id);

        foreach ($history as &$order_state)
            $order_state['text-color'] = Tools::getBrightness($order_state['color']) < 128 ? 'white' : 'black';

        //felek 

            $my_module_name = Configuration::get('CDSIODEMKA_test1');

        //felek end

        // Smarty assign
        $this->tpl_view_vars = array(
            'test'=>$my_module_name,
            'order' => $order,
            'cart' => new Cart($order->id_cart),
            'customer' => $customer,
            'gender' => $gender,
            'customer_addresses' => $customer->getAddresses($this->context->language->id),
            'addresses' => array(
                'delivery' => $addressDelivery,
                'deliveryState' => isset($deliveryState) ? $deliveryState : null,
                'invoice' => $addressInvoice,
                'invoiceState' => isset($invoiceState) ? $invoiceState : null
            ),
            'customerStats' => $customer->getStats(),
            'products' => $products,
            'discounts' => $order->getCartRules(),
            'orders_total_paid_tax_incl' => $order->getOrdersTotalPaid(), // Get the sum of total_paid_tax_incl of the order with similar reference
            'total_paid' => $order->getTotalPaid(),
            'returns' => OrderReturn::getOrdersReturn($order->id_customer, $order->id),
            'customer_thread_message' => CustomerThread::getCustomerMessages($order->id_customer, null, $order->id),
            'orderMessages' => OrderMessage::getOrderMessages($order->id_lang),
            'messages' => Message::getMessagesByOrderId($order->id, true),
            'carrier' => new Carrier($order->id_carrier),
            'history' => $history,
            'states' => OrderState::getOrderStates($this->context->language->id),
            'warehouse_list' => $warehouse_list,
            'sources' => ConnectionsSource::getOrderSources($order->id),
            'currentState' => $order->getCurrentOrderState(),
            'currency' => new Currency($order->id_currency),
            'currencies' => Currency::getCurrenciesByIdShop($order->id_shop),
            'previousOrder' => $order->getPreviousOrderId(),
            'nextOrder' => $order->getNextOrderId(),
            'current_index' => self::$currentIndex,
            'carrierModuleCall' => $carrier_module_call,
            'iso_code_lang' => $this->context->language->iso_code,
            'id_lang' => $this->context->language->id,
            'can_edit' => ($this->tabAccess['edit'] == 1),
            'current_id_lang' => $this->context->language->id,
            'invoices_collection' => $order->getInvoicesCollection(),
            'not_paid_invoices_collection' => $order->getNotPaidInvoicesCollection(),
            'payment_methods' => $payment_methods,
            'invoice_management_active' => Configuration::get('PS_INVOICE', null, null, $order->id_shop),
            'display_warehouse' => (int)Configuration::get('PS_ADVANCED_STOCK_MANAGEMENT'),
            'HOOK_CONTENT_ORDER' => Hook::exec('displayAdminOrderContentOrder', array(
                'order' => $order,
                'products' => $products,
                'customer' => $customer)
            ),
            'HOOK_CONTENT_SHIP' => Hook::exec('displayAdminOrderContentShip', array(
                'order' => $order,
                'products' => $products,
                'customer' => $customer)
            ),
            'HOOK_TAB_ORDER' => Hook::exec('displayAdminOrderTabOrder', array(
                'order' => $order,
                'products' => $products,
                'customer' => $customer)
            ),
            'HOOK_TAB_SHIP' => Hook::exec('displayAdminOrderTabShip', array(
                'order' => $order,
                'products' => $products,
                'customer' => $customer)
            ),
        );

        return AdminOrdersController::renderView();
    }
}
```

So long story short. Where I have to put templates and controllers in mymodule to override them, and how can I add new form or link inside template, and than run my method in controller...
Thanks in advance

Comment: solved. In order to override AdminOrder, you have to register new hook and attach function to that hook inside of mymodule.php

Comment: This may seem posted awhile ago but I am facing a similar problem. I have created the module and tested a function which I displayed with .tpl file. May I know how you managed to override AdminOrdersController.php in your custom module? Basically I just want to add a carrier filter and mass update of the orders. I could do that by editing the core files which I am not going to do. Instead I am creating a module just for this feature.

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46641568/prestashop-1-6-display-orders-with-carriers-in-custom-module?noredirect=1#comment80267551_46641568